# Vimeo live stream api "error_code": 2230

Tags: vimeo, live-streaming, vimeo-api

I was trying Vimeo live streaming API and was following this guide https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/events.

However at step 2: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/events#managing-a-live-event-step-2
I am getting this :

```
{
 "error": "Unable to upload a video. Please contact the app's creator.",
    "link": null,
    "developer_message": "Invalid upload approach provided. The only valid approach for versions greater than 3.0 are `streaming`, `pull`, ' .\n                '`post`, and `tus`.",
    "error_code": 2230
}
```

my curl request looks like this :

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos' \
--header 'Authorization: bearer {token}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json' \
--data-raw '{ "upload": { "approach": "live" } }'
```

I have a premium account and the token is correct. I tried other values for `upload.approach` as suggested in the error message but nothing works for live streaming. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're a Vimeo Premium member, an Enterprise account is required to access the Live API:

> To qualify, you must be a Vimeo Enterprise customer or a Vimeo development partner.

See the first bullet point here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/live/events#before-you-begin

Comment: https://vimeo.com/features/livestreaming as per this premium should have been sufficient. I will check with their support team. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashish Yes premium membership is enough only if you are handling live stream through Vimeo Website.
But accessing through api for events you must have Enterprise membership.
We can't use without Enterprise version, even we also suffering from the same issue.
They also mentioned this one under pricing (check image) and I was told that they did this intentionally.

[image]